# Is it equivalent of wpf's dependency property inheritance in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms application on which I need equivalent of Wpf's dependency  [property inheritance](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjKy-bSxMvRAhVBfhoKHScxAI4QFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms753197(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNF41QzICeGBs3QAqZy8eHl_9uQVWw&sig2=cH0B-MydQQMxuphKjLj9KQ&bvm=bv.144224172,d.d24). Is such feature implemented?

Answer (score 1):

This has not been implemented in Xamarin.Forms. Written at time of 2.3.2 stable release.